# localstorage not defined ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

i'm trying to import "local storage" from 'ionic-angular' and it says me
"LocalStorage is not defined"..
in addtion I got this error

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>   at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:153:20)
>   at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:165:18)
>   at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:165:18)
>   at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:165:18)
>   at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:165:18)
>   at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:165:18)
>   at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:165:18)
>   at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:165:18)
>   at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:165:18)
>   at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:165:18)

first time I got these error on this morning. yesterday I worked fine with another ionic 2 project.

by the way, that's my code

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import {Storage,LocalStorage} from 'ionic-angular';



/*
  Generated class for the Admin page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-admin',
  templateUrl: 'admin.html'
})
export class AdminPage {
  data: any;
  public local: Storage;
  public getsession:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.data={};
    this.data.title="";
    this.data.desc="";
    this.local=new Storage(LocalStorage);
    this.local.set('session','true');

    this.getsession=this.local.get('session');
    this.getsession.then((value)=>{
      let x=value;
      console.log(x);

    })


  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ionic storage has moved to '@ionic/storage'
as of rc.0

so

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
```

You can't specify whether its localstorage/sql or anything. But it uses each in order until its able to use one.

Just create an instance and use it

```
new Storage().set("key","value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Old Question... but it just came up in my Google Results:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
```

Current as of RC4